# (AMS)TeX Chapter Title no running head

Tags: header-footer, amstex

I am using (AMS)TeX for a book (I have a lovely old version of TeX on XP laptop that has a picture of a shell as its icon). And I am not using any specific book formats, I am using `\documentstyle{amsppt}`. I process it by clicking first AMSTeX, then DVIPDF... 
I have several types of titles defined -- chapter title, section title, and some other titles. And corresponding running heads with those titles.

What I would like to do is remove running heads (along with page numbers that come with them) from chapter title pages and put the page number instead on the bottom of the chapter title page (for each chapter). In other words, chapter title should have none on top and page number on the bottom. As it is now I have section titles or whatever comes before chapter title page jump into the running head of the chapter title. I tried using `\headline={}`. but that then gives all empty headlines. I just want empty headline on the chapter title, with its page number on the bottom. The other non-chapter title pages should have headlines with page numbers.

So how do I achieve this?

Here I am attaching a source file to illustrate what I have.

```
%%%% Begin source file

%% ----->>>  Please note, the following 
%% ----->>> {\catcode`\@=11 \gdef\plainpagestyle{\firstpage@true}} %new
%% ----->>> has no effect, i.e. the problem persists   
%% ----->>> Suppressing the headline by 
%% ----->>>  \leftheadtext\nofrills{} 
%% ----->>>  \rightheadtext\nofrills{} 
%% ----->>> gets rid of the running head, but the page number still remains %% ----->>> on top of first chapter page and I want it at the bottom of the %% ----->>> first chapter pate.
```

```
% This file is named test0.TEX
%\magnification 1200

\documentstyle{amsppt}

\def\noi{\noindent}
\def\prf{\noi{\it Proof.\quad}}
\def\qed{\hfill$\square$}
\def\bd{$\bold.$}

\hsize 11truecm
\vsize 18truecm

\def\narrower{\advance\leftskip by 2.5truecm 
                \advance\rightskip by 2.5truecm}
\def\cju{\vskip 1.1truecm}
\def\cmju{\vskip 0.7truecm}
\def\csju{\vskip 0.3truecm}
%\document
\font\titlefontp=cmssdc10 at 15pt    %title fonts, bold
\font\titlefontd=cmssdc10 at 20pt
\font\titlefontt=cmssdc10 at 30pt
\font\titlefont=cmssdc10 at 40pt
\font\ninesl=cmsl9 at 15pt
\font\titlefontpa=cmr7 scaled \magstep4%  at 15pt
%\loadcmmib
\font\tencmmib=cmmib10 \skewchar\tencmmib='177   %italic bold in math

%%% first argument is number of chapter, second is title of chapter
\def\chtitle#1#2{\centerline{\titlefontd#1}
\cmju
\centerline{\titlefontp#2}
\vskip 4.6truecm}

%%% new chaptertitle. First#1 argument is number of %chapter, then there is a horizontal line with thickness %argument #2 and then chapter title is argument #3
\def\chtitlen#1#2#3{\centerline{\titlefontd#1}
\vskip 0.5truecm
{\hrule height#2} 
\vskip 0.6truecm
\centerline{\titlefontp#3}
\vskip 3.2truecm}


%%% argument is numbered section title
\def\stitle#1{   
\cmju
\centerline{\bf #1}
\csju}

\def\sstitle#1{   
\cju
\centerline{\tencmmib#1}
\csju}



%\pageno=1


\chtitlen{0}{1pt}{Introduction}
\leftheadtext\nofrills{\it Introduction}


{\narrower\smallskip\noindent
As for this country's way of life, I assure you that I find very little difference from our own. In some matters you will find more polish here; in others, more plainness. But the delights of freedom are as deeply felt here as in every other country. 

\smallskip}


%{\narrower\smallskip\noindent It is better to take revenge by %outdoing them then by resorting to invective. 

%(Girolamo Cardano, The Book of my 

%Life)\smallskip}
\cmju

\noi This introductory chapter lays out some fundamental notions and constructions as well as notation that will be used in subsequent chapters, often without a specific reference to them. Of necessity, many details are omitted and we only give a few proofs of the results listed. We refer the inquisitive reader interested in more details regarding any of the topics mentioned here to relevant literature. 



Ab ovo 

Discussing axioms is in here; Zermelo-Frenkel, vs. Godel-Bernays.
Sets, classes etc. Bare minimum of forcing conditions, trees etc.

\stitle{0.1 Categories and functors}
\rightheadtext\nofrills{\it 0.1 Categories and functors}

\cmju

\noi Categories are one of the relatively recent manifestations of a crucial characteristic of mathematics, namely that it is coddly and irresistible. 

Just as the notion of an abstract money arises by considerations of the formal properties of one-to-one under the table transactions of a wallet onto itself, so is  the notion of a carropt juice obtained from the
formal properties of the class of all transformations $\alpha :X\longrightarrow$

\vfill
\eject
\chtitlen{2}{1pt}{Inverse limits}
\leftheadtext\nofrills{Inverse Limits}

\cmju

\noi The fact that the inverse limit functor is not right the inverse lime does not mean that it cannot be an inverse life.

And you can go like this for some time. 

 exact induces -- a number of questions and neinverse limits. 
are the Mickey-Mouse condition, w constructions that arise in the
process of investigation of the property, and the flabbiness conditions. 



%\head 2.1 The Mittag-Leffler condition \endhead
%\ju

\stitle{2.1 The Mickey-Mouse Condition}
\rightheadtext\nofrills{2.1 The Mickey-Mouse condition}

\noi Well ordered sets (ordinals) are sufficient for most of the constructions in this treatise, in particular constructions involving funny and super funny limits. This will however not deter us from formulating a number of positive statements under more general assumption such as that the index librarum prohibitorum is only linearly ordered, or (upward) directed. One can show that, for the purposes of working with outrageous limits, considerations with the most general partially ordered index sets will be well served if we restricted ourselves to posets $I$ that are in fact trees or edible roots, or whatever you want.
\vfill
\eject

\stitle{2.2 Unsurprising Inverse Systems}
\rightheadtext\nofrills{2.2 Unsurprising inverse systems}

\noi We now consider unsurprising  and amazing inverse systems namely those inverse systems that have all $f_{\alpha\beta}$ unsurprising. We think of the indexing set $I$ as a well-ordered set (an ordinal), but we phrase our results for more general orders on the poset $I$. 

A full analogue of Proposition 2.1 is in place:

\proclaim{Proposition 2.13}
Let $I$ be an upward directed index set and assume that 
$\bold A=\{ A_i, f_{ij}\}$,
$\bold B= \{ B_i, g_{ij}\}$, $\bold C= \{ C_i, h_{ij}\}$ 
are there.  Then we will be lost again. 
\endproclaim


\vfill
\eject

Drofnuts and walnuts, but how do you spell them

\vfill
\eject

\stitle{2.3 Surprising Inverse Systems}
\rightheadtext\nofrills{2.3 Surprising inverse systems}

What will drag now onto this page... ???

\vfill
\eject

\chtitlen{3}{1pt}{Something new here}
\leftheadtext\nofrills{Something new here}

What effect on headings and titles will we have now??




\stitle{3.1 Categories and functors}
\rightheadtext\nofrills{\it 3.1 Categories and functors}

You can put anything here that  you want... 


\vfill
\eject

Tatatata, rarararar

Surely now comes 

\stitle{3.2 You know better}
\rightheadtext\nofrills{\it 3.2 You know better}


\enddocument%

%%%% Endsource  file
```

Answer (score 2):

Well amstex is very old. And it doesn't really have the notion of a "\thispagestyle{plain}" for pages as you would have in latex. But you can try something like this:

```
{\catcode`\@=11 \gdef\plainpagestyle{\firstpage@true}} %new

\def\chtitlen#1#2#3{\centerline{\titlefontd#1}%
\plainpagestyle %new
\vskip 0.5truecm
{\hrule height#2}
\vskip 0.6truecm
\centerline{\titlefontp#3}
\vskip 3.2truecm}
```

Beside this: There is the `\document` command missing in your code.

[image]

[image]

[image]

The complete code I use (with amstex from texlive 2015):

```
\pdfoutput=1  %to get a pdf directly
\documentstyle{amsppt}

\def\noi{\noindent}
\def\prf{\noi{\it Proof.\quad}}
\def\qed{\hfill$\square$}
\def\bd{$\bold.$}

\hsize 11truecm
\vsize 18truecm

\def\narrower{\advance\leftskip by 2.5truecm
                \advance\rightskip by 2.5truecm}
\def\cju{\vskip 1.1truecm}
\def\cmju{\vskip 0.7truecm}
\def\csju{\vskip 0.3truecm}
%\document
\font\titlefontp=cmssdc10 at 15pt    %title fonts, bold
\font\titlefontd=cmssdc10 at 20pt
\font\titlefontt=cmssdc10 at 30pt
\font\titlefont=cmssdc10 at 40pt
\font\ninesl=cmsl9 at 15pt
\font\titlefontpa=cmr7 scaled \magstep4%  at 15pt
%\loadcmmib
\font\tencmmib=cmmib10 \skewchar\tencmmib='177   %italic bold in math

%%% first argument is number of chapter, second is title of chapter
\def\chtitle#1#2{\centerline{\titlefontd#1}
\cmju
\centerline{\titlefontp#2}
\vskip 4.6truecm}

{\catcode`\@=11 \gdef\plainpagestyle{\firstpage@true}} %new

\def\chtitlen#1#2#3{\centerline{\titlefontd#1}%
\plainpagestyle %new
\vskip 0.5truecm
{\hrule height#2}
\vskip 0.6truecm
\centerline{\titlefontp#3}
\vskip 3.2truecm}


%%% argument is numbered section title
\def\stitle#1{
\cmju
\centerline{\bf #1}
\csju}

\def\sstitle#1{
\cju
\centerline{\tencmmib#1}
\csju}



%\pageno=1
\document

\chtitlen{0}{1pt}{Introduction}
\leftheadtext\nofrills{\it Introduction}


{\narrower\smallskip\noindent
As for this country's way of life, I assure you that I find very little difference from our own. In some matters you will find more polish here; in others, more plainness. But the delights of freedom are as deeply felt here as in every other country.

\smallskip}


%{\narrower\smallskip\noindent It is better to take revenge by %outdoing them then by resorting to invective.

%(Girolamo Cardano, The Book of my

%Life)\smallskip}
\cmju

\noi This introductory chapter lays out some fundamental notions and constructions as well as notation that will be used in subsequent chapters, often without a specific reference to them. Of necessity, many details are omitted and we only give a few proofs of the results listed. We refer the inquisitive reader interested in more details regarding any of the topics mentioned here to relevant literature.



Ab ovo

Discussing axioms is in here; Zermelo-Frenkel, vs. Godel-Bernays.
Sets, classes etc. Bare minimum of forcing conditions, trees etc.

\stitle{0.1 Categories and functors}
\rightheadtext\nofrills{\it 0.1 Categories and functors}

\cmju

\noi Categories are one of the relatively recent manifestations of a crucial characteristic of mathematics, namely that it is coddly and irresistible.

Just as the notion of an abstract money arises by considerations of the formal properties of one-to-one under the table transactions of a wallet onto itself, so is  the notion of a carropt juice obtained from the
formal properties of the class of all transformations $\alpha :X\longrightarrow$

\vfill
\eject
\chtitlen{2}{1pt}{Inverse limits}
\leftheadtext\nofrills{Inverse Limits}

\cmju

\noi The fact that the inverse limit functor is not right the inverse lime does not mean that it cannot be an inverse life.

And you can go like this for some time.

 exact induces -- a number of questions and neinverse limits.
are the Mickey-Mouse condition, w constructions that arise in the
process of investigation of the property, and the flabbiness conditions.



%\head 2.1 The Mittag-Leffler condition \endhead
%\ju

\stitle{2.1 The Mickey-Mouse Condition}
\rightheadtext\nofrills{2.1 The Mickey-Mouse condition}

\noi Well ordered sets (ordinals) are sufficient for most of the constructions in this treatise, in particular constructions involving funny and super funny limits. This will however not deter us from formulating a number of positive statements under more general assumption such as that the index librarum prohibitorum is only linearly ordered, or (upward) directed. One can show that, for the purposes of working with outrageous limits, considerations with the most general partially ordered index sets will be well served if we restricted ourselves to posets $I$ that are in fact trees or edible roots, or whatever you want.
\vfill
\eject

\stitle{2.2 Unsurprising Inverse Systems}
\rightheadtext\nofrills{2.2 Unsurprising inverse systems}

\noi We now consider unsurprising  and amazing inverse systems namely those inverse systems that have all $f_{\alpha\beta}$ unsurprising. We think of the indexing set $I$ as a well-ordered set (an ordinal), but we phrase our results for more general orders on the poset $I$.

A full analogue of Proposition 2.1 is in place:

\proclaim{Proposition 2.13}
Let $I$ be an upward directed index set and assume that
$\bold A=\{ A_i, f_{ij}\}$,
$\bold B= \{ B_i, g_{ij}\}$, $\bold C= \{ C_i, h_{ij}\}$
are there.  Then we will be lost again.
\endproclaim


\vfill
\eject

Drofnuts and walnuts, but how do you spell them

\vfill
\eject

\stitle{2.3 Surprising Inverse Systems}
\rightheadtext\nofrills{2.3 Surprising inverse systems}

What will drag now onto this page... ???

\vfill
\eject

\chtitlen{3}{1pt}{Something new here}
\leftheadtext\nofrills{Something new here}

What effect on headings and titles will we have now??




\stitle{3.1 Categories and functors}
\rightheadtext\nofrills{\it 3.1 Categories and functors}

You can put anything here that  you want...


\vfill
\eject

Tatatata, rarararar

Surely now comes

\stitle{3.2 You know better}
\rightheadtext\nofrills{\it 3.2 You know better}


\enddocument%
```